# Adding UIImageView to custom UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Is this a proper way or are there better solutions?

Thanks a lot!

`Code` (rowAtIndexPath)

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 50, 20, 20)];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) :)

Comment: I'd just use [cell addSubview:imageView]. But for the rest it looks OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your views to cell's contentView not cell's view. Here's an example:

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 50, 20, 20)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: I tried that. I created a prototype cell in IB which has no contentView outlet. (Don't ask me why ...) Solved the problem using a custom .h file for the prototype and a IBConnection to the custom image view. I'm using a custom button now (anyway) because I decided to capture a touch event with the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.size.height, 20, 20)];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

It is correct one.
for large list of UITableView.
If you use `[cell addSubview:]` it will look like flickering for large list.

Answer (score 0):

There is my code and it work well.Hope it helps you.

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.size.height, 20, 20)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3

```
let imgView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 500, y: 50, width: 70, height: 70)) 
     //CALayer for rounded image 
        let imageCALayer : CALayer = imgView.layer
        imageCALayer.cornerRadius = 35
        imageCALayer.masksToBounds = true
        imgView.image = UIImage(string: "Icon.png")
        cell.contentView.addSubview(imgView)
```